# Find the limit of the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{4^n+x^{2n}}}, x \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So, I need to find a limit of the sequence of functions: $$\frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{4^n+x^{2n}}}$$ if $x \ge 0$

So, I assume, I must do it for intervals. If $x \in [0, 1[ $, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{4^n+x^{2n}}} = 0$$

If $x=1,$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^{\infty}}{\sqrt{4^n+1^{\infty}}}= \frac{e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} (x-1) (n+2)}}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{4^n+x^{2n}}}$$

I think what I've done is really incorrect, but liked to know what is the way to do these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your approach will work very well, although your idea of the limit depending on the intervals is correct, as shown later. Instead, note for $x = 0$, the limit is $0$. Then, for $x \gt 0$,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{4^n+x^{2n}}} & = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{(2)^{2n}+x^{2n}}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{\sqrt{x^{2n}\left((\frac{2}{x})^{2n}+1\right)}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{x^n\sqrt{(\frac{2}{x})^{2n}+1}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{(\frac{2}{x})^{2n}+1}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, for $x \lt 2$, since $\frac{2}{x} \gt 1$ so $\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{2n} \to \infty$, the limit becomes $0$. For $x = 2$, the limit becomes $\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} = 2\sqrt{2}$. Finally, for $x \gt 2$, since $\frac{2}{x} \lt 1$ so $\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{2n} \to 0$, the limit becomes $x^2$.